# Why is php script not deleting the table?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I've quickly made a page that shows the current items in the database. I've created the function to adjust stocks levels but I am now trying to add the function to delete items. For some reason all it does is reduce the stock level to 0 but doesn't delete the item from the database.

Also would it be possible/better to put the code the generates the table into another file and load it here? As I need it to auto update when you run either the stock update or deletion function.

AJAX/HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#dataSubmit').on('submit',function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url:'files/update.php',
        data:$(dataSubmit).serialize(),
        type:'POST',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if(data != "Error") {
               $("#data").html(data).show().fadeOut(9000);
            }
            else {
               $("#data").html(data).show().fadeOut(9000);
            }
        },
        error:function(data){
            $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("dataSubmit").reset();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#deleteItem').on('dsubmit',function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url:'files/delete.php',
        data:$(deleteItem).serialize(),
        type:'POST',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if(data != "Error") {
                   $("#datad").html(data).show().fadeOut(9000);
                }
                else {
                   $("#datad").html(data).show().fadeOut(9000);
                }
        },
        error:function(data){
            $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("deleteItem").reset();
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h2> Update Stock Levels </h2>
<form name="dataSubmit" id="dataSubmit" action="">
Product ID: <input type="number" name="Product_ID" value=""><br>
New Stock Amount: <input type="text" name="Product_Stock" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" > 
<div id="data"></div>

<h2> Delete Items </h2>
<form name="deleteItem" id="deleteItem" action="">
Product ID: <input type="number" name="Product_ID" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" name="dsubmit"  >
<div id="datad"></div>





<?php
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Id</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Product Description</th>    <th>Product Price</th><th>Product Stock Amount</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
function __construct($it) { 
    parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

function current() {
    return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
}

function beginChildren() { 
    echo "<tr>"; 
} 

function endChildren() { 
    echo "</tr>" . "\n";
} 
} 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "cms";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,         $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Desc, Product_Price, Product_Stock FROM Products"); 
$stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as     $k=>$v) { 
    echo $v;
}
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP CODE

```
 <?php

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
try {
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$pdo ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "DELETE FROM Products WHERE Product_ID = :Product_ID";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':Product_ID', $_POST['Product_ID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);   
$stmt->execute();



?>
```

Comment: Too much code. You need to do more troubleshooting and narrow it down to at least the php or javascript code. YUou've posted so much code it is implied that you haven't tried to debug this yourself.

Comment: I have tried to debug it. I know where the issue is coming from. When I remove the deletion form it works but I can't figure out why when all the variables are separate.

Comment: And where are the variables `dataSubmit` and `dataSubmit` declared? `data:$(dataSubmit).serialize(),` and `data:$(deleteItem).serialize(),` What is `dsubmit` event? `$('#deleteItem').on('dsubmit',function(e){`

Comment: Sidenote: You have a missing `</form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding to a submit event on the delete action, you have a typo

```
$('#deleteItem').on('dsubmit',function(e){
                     ^
```

The form is just submitting instead.

Comment: I'm confused as its working for all my other functions, just not this one. What do I need to change?